# Guardar tokens em array dinâmico em C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação de consola que funciona como uma `shell` (usando processos para processar comandos enviados via `stdin`). Ao introduzir o comando a processar com `fgets(command, 1024, stdin)` guarda o comando todo e queria dividir a `string` em várias `strings` separadas por espaços (guardar os diferentes argumentos do comando). Ao fazer um ciclo `while(argumento != null)` queria guardar cada argumento num vetor auxiliar. Como é que crio um vetor dinâmico e dentro do ciclo atribuo o valor do argumento para a posição n do vetor (por ordem crescente claro)? Abaixo tenho o código que estou a usar para o pretendido.

```
    char *command = malloc(MAX_COMMAND_SIZE);
    int arg_counter = 0;

    char **command_args;

    fgets(command, MAX_COMMAND_SIZE, stdin);

    char *command_arg = strtok(command, DELIM);

    while(command_arg != NULL)
    {
        printf("arg %d: %s\n", arg_counter, command_arg);

        strcpy(command_args[arg_counter], command_arg);

        arg_counter++;

        command_arg = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
    }
```

Notas:

```
MAX_COMMAND_SIZE = 1024
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente sua dúvida mas você já avaliou o uso da função `strtok` de `<string.h>`?

Comment: Sim já consigo mostrar cada token por linha e queria guardar cada token num array dinâmico (vai crescendo de acordo com o comando inserido).